# Spark on YARN: yarn-client vs yarn-cluster: Spark Driver memory differences

Tags: apache-spark, memory-management, hadoop-yarn, heap-memory, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm doing some benchmarks and I look also at the memory issues in Spark. When running my Spark Application I saw, that the memory of the Spark Driver process differs, depending on the deployment-mode I run the app in.

The table below shows the different values that my Spark UI showed in the executors -> driver section of the app. I set the driver memory per spark-submit parameter --driver-memory.

```
--driver-memory parameter   | yarn-client       | yarn-cluster
==================================================================
1g                          | 511.1 MB          | 511.9 MB
2g                          | 1247.3 MB         | 1140.4 MB
5g                          | 3.4 GB            | 3.1 GB
10g                         | 7.0 GB            | 6.4 GB
20g                         | 14.2 GB           | 13.1 GB
```

I found a calculation on the Internet (https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/), saying, that

```
driverMemory = (driver.memory * scalaOverhead - SystemReserved) * memoryFraction
             = (driver.memory * ~0.96 - 300) * 0.75
```

estimates the memory that is really used for the driver process (the Spark memory without User Memory).

This calculation fits very good for me for the yarn-client mode! But, as you can see in the table, the values differ between both modes, the gap grows when I increase the --driver-memory value.

Do I miss anything here?